# Ajax is not getting data properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

hy

i am trying to submit data using ajax and then get it. i tried this code..

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>

</head>

<body>
<div>

    <form action="voteupdown.php" id="form" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="form-control"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" class="form-control"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

    <div id="result">

    </div>

</div>



<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#form').submit(function(){
           return false;
        });
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            $.get(("voteupdown.php"), function (data) {
                $("#result").html(data);
            });
        });
    });

</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**the voteupdown.php**

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
echo $name;

?>
```

when i simple `echo " hy this is test"`  in my voteupdown.php then the code will work, but when i try to echo the first and last name then it will show the below error.

```
Notice: Undefined index: fname in G:\xampp\htdocs\Questiona-Step1\voteupdown.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: lname in G:\xampp\htdocs\Questiona-Step1\voteupdown.php on line 4
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use `post/ajax` to send data on server instead of `get`

Comment: also if you have ajax you can remove the form action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server side script is expecting data to be POSTed to it, your javascript is sending a GET request. In addition, your GET request is not actually including any of the data.

Assuming you want to keep the server side expecting POST you should change your javascript as follows

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
        var fname = $('#fname').val();
        var lname = $('#lname').val();
        $.post("voteupdown.php"), {
           fname: fname,
           lname: lname
        },function (data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't working because your PHP is expecting data in the `$_POST` variable.
You're also not posting any of your form data to the PHP file.
Try the following:

```
$('body').on('submit', '#form', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'voteupdown.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: formData,
        success: function(result) {
            $('#result').html(result);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            # error handling here
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I like this. Its better than my answer where I was trying to keep the code as close to the OP's original as possible. This is for sure the way I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your form submit call:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){

        $.post(("voteupdown.php"), 

        { 
       fname: $("#fname").val(), 
           lname: $("#lname").val() 
    },

        function (data)
        {
            $("#result").html(data);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You are using $.get method for ajax and you are trying to get val by $_POST. because of this you got this error. Try This hopefully it will help you:

$.post( "voteupdown.php", { fname: $("#fname").val(), lname: $("#lname").val() }, function( data ) {
  $("#result").html(data);
});

or if you wants to get response in json format than use this

$.post( "voteupdown.php", { fname: $("#fname").val(), lname: $("#lname").val() }, function( data ) {
  $("#result").html(data);
}, "json");
```